# Stripe payment in Flutter doesnt recognize decimal value

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I have incorporate Stripe payment into my app
even the `totalAmount` printing return a decimal value " 9.5", into the Stripe page I get 9.00 as value without decimal.

this is my code for calling Stripe:

```
double totalAmount = widget.payment;
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          //Here the function to pay by Card
          RaisedButton(
            elevation: 15,
            color: Colors.orange,
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                spin = true;
              });
              print(totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(3));
              final sessionId = await http.post(
                  'https://us-central1-vibeland-50e11.cloudfunctions.net/create_checkout_session',
                  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                    'price': totalAmount.toString() ?? '10'
                  }));
              var sessID = jsonDecode(sessionId.body)['sessionId'];
              if (sessID != null) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => PaymentScreenWebView(
                        snapshotUser: widget.snapshotUser,
                        payment: widget.payment,
                        snapshot: widget.snapshot,
                        value: widget.value,
                        totalValue: widget.totalValue,
                        sessionId: jsonDecode(sessionId.body)['sessionId']),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
```

any Input?

Comment: Just a heads-up in case you weren't aware of this, but Stripe expects amounts to be provided in a currency’s smallest unit, as a whole integer. So if you wanted to charge $9.50 you would pass in the integer `950` as the amount to Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies.

Comment: then I need to ```*100```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It might also be worthwhile wrapping the entire expressing in `Math.floor` or an equivalent to ensure the provided amount is an integer not a float. So something like `Math.floor(totalAmount * 100)`